# .ToString(int)': no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#

This is my Program.cs:

```
int currentHp = 100;
Potion potion = new Potion(10);
Console.WriteLine(potion.ToString(currentHp));
```

This is my class called Potion.cs

```
private int hpHeal;

public Potion(int hpHeal)
{
    HpHeal = hpHeal;
}
public int HpHeal
{
    get { return hpHeal; }
    set
    {
        hpHeal = value;
    }
}

public override string ToString(int currentHp)
        {
            if (currentHp + hpHeal > 100)
            {
                string result = "";
                result += $"You healed for {100 - currentHp} hp.\n";
                currentHp = 100;
                result += $"Current health: {currentHp} hp.";
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                string result = "";
                currentHp += hpHeal;
                result += $"You healed for{hpHeal} hp.\n";
                result += $"Current health: {currentHp} hp.";
                return result;
            }
        }
```

The line `public override string ToString(int currentHp)` is underlined with an error
`'Potion.ToString(int)': no suitable method found to override` and I don't know why... I'm currently learning how Classes work so don't judje me too hard.

Comment: To override a method, a method in the base class has to exist and be `abstract` or `virtual`. If you look at the base class, `object`'s [ToString method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0), you'll see that its signature is `public virtual string ToString ()`, not `public virtual string ToString(int currentHp)`.

Comment: You can add one or more ToString() versions to your class, besides the one you're overriding, as `public virtual string ToString(int somevalue) { return "something " + somevalue }`. Or non `virtual`, if it's not meant to be overridden (and probably seal the class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToString` is a "predefined" method that cannot take any arguments. In your case, simply rename your method (e.g., to `Stringify`) and remove the `override` keyword from its definition.

Comment: Stringify is not a good name. Using ToString was also not good design. The method is doing to much stuff. Stringifying is just a small part of it. This probably deserves an own class or helper

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to override a method which doesn’t exists at all in the base class.

You need to rename your `ToString` method to some meaningful name as per your business logic like `GetCustomString`

One suggestion, you should also rename `int hpHeal;` because you have same parameter in the constructor, it’s confusing. Better name it something like `_hpHeal`.

And your can also reduce the number of string assignments here, few are unnecessarily affecting performance as string are immutable and it creates a new string when you assign it again.

Comment: There is no need to change ```int hpHeal``` to something else, cause the constructor sends the value it receives to the ```private int hpHeal``` if I express myself correctly. So basically they are the same thing. That's how they teach us at school to make them the same name.

Comment: @Alice https://stackoverflow.com/q/268587/6527049